# sql for each district increment column facility

Tags: postgresql, plsql

I am trying to update a column [facility_id] with incrementing integer for each group of districts. The facility_id needs to start at 1 and end at x pending how many columns each district has. I have been playing with loops all day but I have nothing that works and dread doing this by hand because I have 3,000 rows to manipulate.

[bad table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfSDu.png)

[good table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckgA8.png)

I am new and still learning, please teach.
Thank you!

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) window function to update the column:

```
update tablename 
set Facility_ID = t.rn
from (
  select id, row_number() over (partition by District order by ID) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.ID = tablename.ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=e6961896269acdccfb36b4c78093002a).

Comment: #MicDrop @forpas
I can't say thank you enough, but thank you x ~!